# How do I combine many zoo objects in R

Tags: r, zoo

I have > 100 zoo objects that I would like to combine (`cbind`) into one large zoo object. The zoo objects are stored in my working directory. I have created a list of the file names (with pathway information) and am trying to use this list in do.call to perform cbind.

```
path <- "~/mydata/"

files <- as.list(list.files(path=path, pattern= "*.RData", full.names=TRUE))

big.zoo<-do.call(cbind,files)
```

When I run the above code, it `cbinds` just the file names and their pathways. The `zoo` files are not combined.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: First load the files: `e <- new.env(); for(f in files) load(f, envir = e); do.call("merge", as.list(e))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = length(files)
big.zoo = NULL
for (i in 1:n) {
  temp = load(file[i])
  big.zoo = merge(big.zoo, temp)
}
```

Since I do not have your data, I cannot be sure if this will work,
but if your RData is a zoo object, and all of your file name list has been
loaded properly to 'files', this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, when I run this I get an error. See below.path <- "~my.data/"
> files <- as.list(list.files(path=path, pattern= "*.RData", full.names=TRUE))
> n = length(files)
> big.zoo = NULL
> for (i in 1:n) {
+ temp = load(file[i])
+ big.zoo = merge(big.zoo, temp)
+ }
Error in file[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: From the error message, it should be straight forward. Call `file[1]` and see if it returns character of your file, in your working directory.